# Why this apache rewrite fail?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, character-encoding

I'm using vbulletin 5 , it routes all requests to index.php using this rule

```
# Main Redirect
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?routestring=$1 [L,QSA]
```

it is working fine but I had a weird issue .. when I click a URL contating the Arabic letter "م" the redirect fails and I get 404 ( by Apache not vbulletin )

for example [http://localhost/vb5/forum/main-forum/27-مدرسة](http://localhost/vb5/forum/main-forum/27-%D9%85%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%B3%D8%A9) 
I solved the issue by replacing the rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?routestring=$1 [L,QSA]
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+) index.php?routestring=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and it is working fine now .. I'm Just curious to know why the first one is not working in this scenario !

Comment: You earlier rule is working fine for me

Comment: Maybe this answer sheds some light http://serverfault.com/a/449166/141697